# Set Form Recordsource from a library form to an app table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I came across a challenge trying to set the recordsource in multiple forms stored in a library database. These forms are for generic use, while the data to be accessed are stored in (linked) tables in the app itself.

For example form "frm_settings" (in library accde)
(partial code)

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strTblName As String
    Me.InsideWidth = Cm2Twip(18)
    Me.InsideHeight = Cm2Twip(17.2)
    CenterForm Me.Name, False, False, False
    strTblName = "USysAppSettings"
    If not TableExists(strTblName) Then
        MsgBox "The required table " & strTblName & " is not found or not available.", _
               vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Missing or blocked table"
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo
    End If

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM USysAppSettings;"

    Me.RecordSource = strSQL
End
```

According to [this post][1] i have to add an "IN" clause to the recordsource string:

> If the form references tables or queries in the app you need to set
>   the recordsource of the form in the On Open Event. You also need to
>   add the "IN C:\Program Files\MyDirectory\MyApp.MDB" clause to any
>   queries referencing tables in your apps MDB.

Anyone experience with this? Does this mean that forms in the library db are only possible to work as unbound forms? If so, I need to create various procedures to read, delete and update the tables using DAO/ADO.

Art

Comment: That is only to use an _external_ database. For a local or a linked table, your current code will do.

Comment: You can use bound forms with external recordsets. Please provide an attempt, normally this should just work after adding the `IN` clause (or as Gustav said, with a linked table it should also just work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be sure that a reference to a table or simplified SQL string will not work, I copied a form from the library database to the app (frm_settings_local) and tried to open it. It worked flawless.

Continuing on the solution (old post) on the page http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/addins.htm and despite I work in Accesss x64 2016, I tried changing the SQL and now adding quotation marks around the app path/name string.

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM USysAppSettings IN '" & CurrentProject.FullName & "';"
```

This worked! This means that, when using forms in a library database:

1. You cannot use a table name (and possibly neither a query too) as
   form.recordsource if this table (or query) is stored in the app itself.
2. You have to add "IN '[full path to and name of the app]';" to the record
   source SQL string.

Hope this helps others with the same question.